# How to send UIButton's dragging event

Tags: iphone, events, uibutton, touch, uiresponder

---

I have a UIButton, and its superView has touch events.
When the button started dragging i want pass the button and keep go from its superView's touchesMoved function, thats what my problem is.

i tried customize the button, and use its touch events like below;

```
@implementation MyButton

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event]; 
}


@end
```

but it doesnt work, touches didnt go to its superView's touchesMoved function..
can anyone please help me?